# get position from specific position to end window

Tags: javascript

hi all 
how i can get position from specific position to end window (Browser) dynamic

Comment: Are you asking how you can get the vertical distance, in pixels, between a given point and the lower edge of the viewable part of the current page?

Answer (score 0):

First, you could hook the mouseMove event on the html . Then, you close the windows when the mouse position inside assigned range.

Here is a simple example for you. The windows automatically close when the mouse move in the range 100 < X < 105 and 100 < Y < 105.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title> Close Windows</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkPos()
{
    var s = 'X=' + window.event.clientX +  ' Y=' + window.event.clientY ;
    document.getElementById('divCoord').innerText = s;
    if(window.event.clientX > 100 && window.event.clientX < 105 && window.event.clientY > 100 & window.event.clientY < 105) {
    window.close();
}
}  

</script></head>
<body onmousemove=checkPos()>
<div id="divCoord"></div>
</body></html>
```